# Reset Admin Password on Ricoh MP 350+

Tags: passwords, printer, network-printer, password-recovery, fax

The device was acquired through a re-seller from an unknown seller. Problem is the admin account has been set up and no one knows the password or even username. Does anyone know of a way to reset the password without having to reconfigure the device? Tried using admin:password, supervisor:*blank*, supervisor1:*blank*, *blank*:sysadm, administrator and so on in the Web Image Portal to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to reset the printer to factory defaults. That will reset everything, including passwords. I found this [here](https://www.ehow.co.uk/how_6767608_reset-ricoh-factory-settings.html):

> Press the "./*" key and the "#" key on the Ricoh copier at the same
> time and hold for 10 seconds. Nothing will seem to happen until you
> hold both buttons down for the full 10 seconds. Once 10 seconds is
> reached, the copier will shut down and begin to reboot. During this
> process, the Ricoh is resetting itself to factory default settings.

It does not list which models it applies to but it's worth a try.